# Did Muammar al-Gaddafi have 95% popular support even when he was being overthrown

Tags: africa, gaddafi, democracy

I just watched [The illuminati Exposed By Muammar Gaddafi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQzFjac1A1M) on YouTube. It was very interesting, but at one point they said that there was a pro-Gaddafi rally in the Tripoli with 1.7 million people or 95% of Tripoli. This rally occured during the civil war.

Did this rally really happen?

Was there a large percent support for Gaddafi during the civil war?

Comment: When men with guns come to your home and tell you that you get to join a giant rally for the ruler... well you attend  the rally for the ruler even if you do not really agree.  Popularity polls in nations where freedom of expersion is not the norm are going to be unreliable.

Comment: In the country I was born into (Czechoslovakia), the National Coalition led by the Communist Party always secured 99.2% to 99.8% popular election outcomes.  It certainly helped that the law at the time prevented any other ticket from running.  Do not misunderstand me: these numbers said nothing at all about the level of popular support and everybody knew that.  The best you can say that the level of popular support as you know it was just - undefined.

Comment: Even if that claim was true, that does not imply 95% popular support, Tripoli was his power base and support for him in other areas (e.g. populated by different tribes) would not be similar, and not all participants would be from Tripoli.

Comment: Cannot find a research confirmed answer for this question, however, news reports such as these ones-http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-13998833, http://news.sky.com/story/868797/thousands-bussed-in-to-pro-gaddafi-rally from several sources surely confirm only several to tens of thousands people and not a million of people as claimed by the OP and others here-http://www.intifada-palestine.com/2011/07/one-third-of-libya-turns-out-to-support-qaddafi-in-worlds-largest-march-ever/!

Comment: The  CIA estimated population of Tripoli the capital of Libya was 1.095 million in 2009 and 1.126 million as of 2015 referring to these documents-https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/print/country/countrypdf_ly.pdf and https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/ly.html. 95% of that should more or less equal to 1040250 or 1069700 which is less than the claimed 1.7 million people!